# Difference between Type casting and Up/Down casting in inheritance [Java]?

Tags: java, inheritance, types, casting

We know the following:: *(Edit 20210101_0059 EST)*

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myInt = 9;
    double myDouble = (double) myInt; // casting: int to double 
  }
}
```

> Type casting is when you assign a value of one primitive data type to another type.

> Widening Casting (automatically) - converting a smaller type to a larger type size
> byte -> short -> char -> int -> long -> float -> double
> https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_type_casting.asp

---

*Question*::

What is the difference between Type casting and Upcasting / Downcasting?
How Type casting works?

Is that upcasting in the example? If so, does it mean integers inherit from double? (which I don't think so)

---

---

***Update Below 20210101_0059~0154 EST***

I change the line

```
double myDouble = myInt; // casting: int to double
// change to >>
double myDouble = (double) myInt; // casting: int to double
```

Because my intention was to talk about casting.
That mistake led people to start to talk about type conversion instead of casting.

---

By now, base on the answers, I know there is no up/downcasting in Java Language Specification.
And I briefly looked through [5.5. Casting Contexts & 5.5.1. Reference Type Casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)

*Question*::

So, what exactly is a casting? is "casting" basically just "type conversion"?

And there are many types of casting (/ type conversion) right?

---

*Questions (for confirmation)*::

1.
And so, casting does not necessary exist between superclass and subclass (*ie: casting does not only exist in 2 class with inheritance relationship*), right?

2.
Usually, when we talk about up/downcasting, we are using it in "Reference Type Casting".
But in our case `double myDouble = (double) myInt;` there is no up/downcasting.
And, in both cases, the castings (Up/Down casting & int-double casting) are just "type conversion". Right?

3.
In short, the only difference between them are just:

Type casting -- a general term for casting.

Up/Down casting -- a term only used in "Reference Type Casting", which involves inheritance.

casting "byte short char int long float  double" (eg: `double myDouble = (double) myInt;`) -- (just a different type of casting that is not used in "Reference Type Casting").

Right?

---

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. That's not casting (and the term is not "type casting", which is about professional actors).

Comment: [If an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> Type casting is when you assign a value of one primitive data type to another type.

This is not true according to the specification. The spec specifies a [cast operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) that looks like this:

```
(some type) some expression
```

e.g.

```
(float)someDouble
```

The spec also specifies that this is a [casting context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

What W3Schools meant by "type casting", the spec calls a "conversion". *Conversions* occurs in *contexts*. And by "upcasting" and "downcasting", W3Schools probably meant "widening conversion" and "narrowing conversion".

This:

```
double myDouble = myInt;
```

is a *conversion* from `int` to `double` (one of the many [widening primitive conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), occurring in an [assignment context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2). No casts were involved.

Compare that to an actual cast:

```
(float)myDouble
```

This is a conversion from `double` to `float` (one of the many [narrowing primitive conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)) occurring in a casting context.

And no, primitive types like `int`, `double`, `float` etc can't inherit from anything. These primitive conversions are "hardcoded"/mandated by the spec, not as a consequence of "`int` inherits from `double`" or anything like that.

Comment: The JLS actually does mention "upcast" and "downcast": *If the conversion is conceptually an "upcast", then the conversion is completely unchecked; no run time test is needed because the conversion is legal in the non-generic type system of the Java Virtual Machine. In contrast, if the conversion is conceptually a "downcast", then the conversion is partially unchecked; even in the non-generic type system of the Java Virtual Machine, a run time check is needed to test the compatibility of the (raw) types involved in the conversion.* Also in 15.20.2, and a couple other places.

Comment: @Dioxin Hmm, apparently it was added in newer versions. In my answer I was referring to the Java 8 spec because that is what I am the most familiar with, which did not have those words at all. Anyway, what OP showed here _still_ isn't upcasting or down casting according to the new version of the spec :)

Answer (score 0):

> Type casting is when you assign a value of one primitive
> data type to another type.

Casting is explicit, by use of a cast operation.  See the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16).

Type casting is a general term. Specific cases are described as upcasting (subclass to superclass) or downcasting (superclass to subcast), but these cases are still type casting.

In expressions such as

```
double myDouble = myInt;
```

there is no cast. This is a [type conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html); specifically a widening primitive conversion.

For reference types, there's a similar concept of widening conversion (from a subtype to a supertype), also narrowing conversion (supertype to subtype).

Type conversions may be implicit.  Casts are used to explicitly force a specific conversion.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding and correct me if I'm wrong.
There are no any terms as "Up Casting" or "Down Casting" in JLS. There are different types of [conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1). Casting is used in some conversions.
There are basic two types of conversions -
1.automatic/implicit.(does not require casting).

- [Widening Primitive Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) - byte to (short to (int to (long to (float to double)))).
  byte, short, int, long, float, double are all primitive data types they are compatible with each other. The target type must be larger than the source type.
  Widening primitive conversion -

> ```
> int i = 5;
> long l = i; //target = long. source = int.
> ```

- [Widening Reference Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) - SubClass to SuperClass/SubType to SuperType
  A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type S to any reference type T, provided S is a subtype of T. That is subclass superclass relation is necessary.
  Widening reference conversion -

> ```
> class SuperClass {}
> class SubClass extends SuperClass {}
> SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
> SuperClass superClass = subClass; //target = SuperClass. source = SubClass.
> ```

- [Boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) - int to Integer / double to Double.
- [Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) - Integer to int / Long to long.

All the above automatic/implicit conversions are done automatically by compiler no casting is used/needed.

2.manual/explicit.(requires casting).
When we try to narrow data, compiler gives us an error "Type mismatch". If the data types are compatible with each other then compiler is telling us that narrowing conversion can result in loss of data and may lose precision and range. but if we are ok with loss of data or we know that there would not be any data loss, we tell compiler to ignore that error by using casting operator "(target type)source". that is we are casting target type on source type.

- [Narrowing Primitive Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) - double to (float to (long to (int to (short to byte)))). byte, short, int, long, float, double are all primitive data types they are compatible with each other.

> ```
> long l = 5;
> //int i = l; //gives - Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int
> int i = (int)l; //adding cast resolves the error//target = int. source = long.
> ```

- [Narrowing Reference Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) - SuperClass to SubClass/SuperType to SubType

> ```
> class SuperClass {}    
> class SubClass extends SuperClass {}   
> SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();    
> //SubClass subClass = superClass; //gives - Type mismatch: cannot convert from SuperClass to SubClass
>                                   //even though the object stored in superClass reference is SubClass
>                                   //object then also compiler does not allow this,
>                                   //because compiler goes by the type of reference.    
> SubClass subClass = (SubClass)superClass; //adding cast resolves the issue//target = SubClass. source = SuperClass.
> ```

If we cast wrongly then it could result in ClassCastException at run-time, to avoid this we can use Type Comparison Operator that is [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator.
widening or narrowing primitive conversions requires primitive datatypes.
widening or narrowing reference conversions requires subclass superclass relation.

and while narrowing we are manually performing casting using casting operator that is called as Type Casting, let it be [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) or [Narrowing Reference Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) it is Type Casting only.